# Skype bot install restriction

Tags: node.js, skype, botframework

I'm working on a bot for Skype with the Microsoft BotFramework and I'm looking for a way to share it only to authorized people. 
I know I can for example display a link to add the bot on a private page, but I think that anyone could then share this link and add the bot to his Skype account.

Has anyone already done that ? Any idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can try making a database of allowed people and restrict the responses only to this people.
You'll need to use the `session.agent` variable to see the user's name to decide if the user it's or not in your allowed people's list.
So, your bot is going to be visible to anyone, but it'll only chat with people you want.

Comment: Agree.  If you have an authenticated service you could also follow an authentication pattern (pass the user a blue link, they click and sign in, and you map that access token to their channelAccount).

Comment: That's what I wanted to do, but i didin't know how to get a unique ID for the skype user in order to store it in my user table. I'm gonna try with "session.agent". THX

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get the session.agent var -> undefined.
    here is a dump of my session :

```
 { domain: 
       { domain: null,
         _events: { error: [Function: onError] },
        _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  _events: { error: [Function] },
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  options: 
   { localizer: undefined,
     autoBatchDelay: 250,
     library: { name: '*', dialogs: [Object], libraries: [Object] },
     actions: { actions: {} },
     middleware: [],
     dialogId: '/',
     dialogArgs: undefined,
     dialogErrorMessage: undefined,
     onSave: [Function],
     onSend: [Function] },
  msgSent: true,
  _isReset: false,
  lastSendTime: 1474355048875,
  batch: 
   [ { type: 'message',
       agent: 'botbuilder',
       source: 'skype',
       address: [Object],
       text: ' help lastMsg lastUser' } ],
  batchStarted: true,
  sendingBatch: false,
  inMiddleware: false,
  library: 
   { name: '*',
     dialogs: { '/': [Object] },
     libraries: { BotBuilder: [Object] } },
  userData: {},
  conversationData: {},
  privateConversationData: {},
  sessionState: 
   { callstack: [ [Object] ],
     lastAccess: 1474355048876,
     version: 0 },
  dialogData: 
   { 'BotBuilder.Data.Intent': '/^help/i',
     'BotBuilder.Data.WaterfallStep': 0 },
  message: 
   { type: 'message',
     timestamp: '2016-09-20T07:04:03.723Z',
     text: 'help',
     entities: [],
     attachments: [],
     address: 
      { id: '2jdYO5OjjEja1zH6',
        channelId: 'skype',
        user: [Object],
        conversation: [Object],
        bot: [Object],
        serviceUrl: 'https://skype.botframework.com',
        useAuth: true },
     source: 'skype',
     agent: 'botbuilder',
     user: 
      { id: '29:1MPrjjbaPcCccdu9BMdA154jiuHUIH4nR7EK9_0p64iEUg',
        name: 'Séverin' } },
  batchTimer: 
   { _idleTimeout: 250,
     _idlePrev: 
      { '0': [Function: listOnTimeout],
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        msecs: 250 },
     _idleNext: 
      { '0': [Function: listOnTimeout],
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        msecs: 250 },
     _idleStart: 364730333,
     _onTimeout: [Function],
     _repeat: false,
     domain: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        members: [Object] } } }
```

How can I get a unique identifier from Skype in order to match it with the user in my databas? Ideally I would like to add a field "skypeId" in my User table.

Thank you